# popover controller not being dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I have this `UIViewController` which is presented as `.popover`.

```
func editSlotPopOver(eventCell:EventCell, gr:UITapGestureRecognizer){

    let location = gr.location(in: eventCell)
    let editAlertController = UIViewController()

    let viewAlert = EditSlotPopOver(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:editAlertController.view.bounds.width  , height: editAlertController.view.bounds.height))
    viewAlert.delegate = self
    viewAlert.setEvent(event: eventCell.event!, cell: eventCell)
    editAlertController.view = viewAlert
    editAlertController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    let popoverMenuViewController:UIPopoverPresentationController = editAlertController.popoverPresentationController!
    popoverMenuViewController.permittedArrowDirections = .any
    editAlertController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    popoverMenuViewController.sourceView = eventCell
    popoverMenuViewController.sourceRect = CGRect(
        x: location.x,
        y: location.y,
        width: 1,
        height: 1)

    present(editAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

The popover is presented as expected:

[image]

However, when I try to delete the cell with this method:

```
func deleteSlot(eventCell: EventCell, id: Int){

    let application = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let id:Int32 = Int32(eventCell.eventId!)
    print(id)
    let context = application.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Slot> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Slot")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "event_id = %d", id)

    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

        let slot = result[0]
        application.managedObjectContext.delete(slot)
        do{
            try context.save()
        }catch let err {
            print(err)

        }
    }catch let error {

        print(error)

    }
    //DISMISS DOESN'T WORK HERE
    self.editAlertController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    eventCell.removeFromSuperview()
    self.calendarView.forceReload(reloadEvent: true)
}
```

The cell is removed from the superview and the objected removed from core data but I am not able to dismiss the popover:

[image]

The 2 functions are declared in the same controller, however `EditSlorPopOver` is a subclass of UIView with a protocol named `EditSlotDelegate`. The delegate is being called but the popover is not being dismissed.

```
protocol EditSlotDelegate {
  func deleteSlot(eventCell: EventCell, id: Int)
}


class EditSlotPopOver: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
     super.init(frame: frame)
     setUpEditButton()
     editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteSlot), for: .touchUpInside)

 }

//.....more code here 

  func deleteSlot(){
     delegate?.deleteSlot(eventCell: eventCell!, id: Int(slotid!))

}

 //.....more code here 


}
```

Comment: @Rajat please see the updated question

Comment: Try calling dismiss on 'self' rather than the `self.editAlertController`. It should be the controller thats presenting the popover that should dismiss it, not the popover dismissing itself.

Comment: @dlbuckley oh my god! I cannot believe it was something so easy. That fixed the problem. Can you please answer so I can accept it. Thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem, moved comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved from a comment:

Try calling dismiss on `self` rather than the `self.editAlertController`. It should be the controller thats presenting the popover that should dismiss it, not the popover dismissing itself.